# Set a variable in a quoted text in php

Tags: php

I was wondering if I can do something like that with php:

```
<?php
die("
<input name='data' type='hidden' value='". $minute=date('i')-15;echo($minute)."'/>");
?>
```

The question is if I can set an variable inside a "die". It would very useful because that way I could see easier the variables and what they mean... Is this possible? If not I think I will try something else. Sorry for my english..this is not my original language.

Comment: 'This code is responsible for my site security.` ... I don't even. Hidden inputs should not be used for anything related to security. I right-click your page, check your source code, and bam! I can see everything.

Comment: And i put TIME-15.So noone will ever realise that is the time.And it is in seconds.Very sensitive.And i have a "blacklist" with all ip's that have tried to hack my site.Clever,isn't it?

Comment: No, it's not really.

Comment: In what way would that prevent me doing something with your site? Btw. You realize that your code would 'work' if you put the variable declaration outside of your die? Or if you would just make a single statement from both (dumping the echo on your way)?

Comment: My site is private(it has a domain but i don't want to make it public-only a few people will know about it).But someone can find it.I have a login page.And if he tries to access the page after login he will get a no access screen and his ip will be introduced in a database.And if he tries again he will get only that no access screen.Simple.I made this because i thoughtthat he will try something like brute-force(not exactly).Maybe he will try to login just sending variables like username ,password to my site generated by a program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, die will avoid any other code to run on it BUT, this is what you need.

Just structure everything before putting in, die doesn't allow that kind of contacts, punctuation, etc.

```
$minutes=$minute=date('i')-15;
$var='<input name="data" type="input" value="'. $minutes .'"/>';
die($var);
```

Comment: Yes.I think I will do it like that.Thank you!

Comment: no problem! hope it helped out .